# h2o.auc( perf , xval =TRUE) - what does this call return?

Tags: h2o

My code is as follows

```
gbm.fit.hex = h2o.gbm(x= xcols , y =1865 , training_frame = tr.hex , distribution = "bernoulli", model_id = "gbm.model" , key = "gbm.model.key" ,                 ntrees = gbm.trees , max_depth = gbm.depth , min_rows = gbm.min.rows ,                  learn_rate = gbm.learn.rate , nbins = 20 , balance_classes = gbm.balance , nfolds = gbm.folds )
```

`perf <- h2o.performance(gbm.fit.hex , tr.hex)
 a = h2o.auc(perf , xval = TRUE)`

What does the auc call return? does it return the AUC on training dataset or on the crossvalidation results?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It retrieves the cross-validated AUC.

Since you set the `nfolds` argument to something non-zero, the `h2o.gbm` function also performs k-fold cross-validation in addition to training a GBM model on the full training set.  In your command, you did not specify a validation set, so the AUC values you can retrieve are training AUC, `h2o.auc(perf, train = TRUE)`, and cross-validated AUC (as above).

If you want to evaluate performance on a separate validation (or test) set, you can pass that frame using the `validation_frame` argument and retrieve the validation AUC using `h2o.auc(perf, valid = TRUE)`.